# Sort a JSON file by value and return it as a dictionary python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I would like to open a JSON file, sort it in ascending order by the 'amount' key and return it as a dictionary. I have tried many other solutions on this website and none of them seemed to have worked.

My code:

```
with open('test.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:  
    result_dict = json.load(f)
    new_dict = sorted(result_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['amount'], reverse=True)
```

'test.json'

```
{"feel": {"amount": 54, "per": "0.20952%"}, "like": {"amount": 145, "per": "0.5626%"}, "so": {"amount": 83, "per": "0.32203%"}}
```

When I run my code above, the output I get is:

```
[('like', {'amount': 145, 'per': '0.5626%'}), ('so', {'amount': 83, 'per': '0.32203%'}), ('feel', {'amount': 54, 'per': '0.20952%'})]
```

The intended output I would like is:

```
{'like': {'amount': 145, 'per': '0.5626%'}, 'so': {'amount': 83, 'per': '0.32203%'}, 'feel': {'amount': 54, 'per': '0.20952%'}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you're saying you have no problem with JSON and thus shouldn't have included that in the question?

Comment: I just included it because I'm not sure if using a regular dictionary or a dictionary pulled from a JSON file will change anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with json.
`sorted()` returns a list, not a dict. Since this list it returns is a list of tuples, and each tuple is a key-value pair for a dictionary, you can create a dict by simply passing this list to `dict()`:

```
with open('test.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:  
    result_dict = json.load(f)
    new_list = sorted(result_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['amount'], reverse=True)
    new_dict = dict(new_list)
```

Note that sorting a dict is pretty pointless because what does "order" mean in a data structure that has a key and not an index?

Answer (score -1):

Running your code and getting differnet result made me a little bit confused. But what I have come up with is pretty close to your code with a little bit of edit:

```py
import json
data = json.loads('{"feel": {"amount": 54, "per": "0.20952%"}, "like": {"amount": 145, "per": "0.5626%"}, "so": {"amount": 83, "per": "0.32203%"}}')
sortedKeys = sorted(data, key=lambda item: data[item]["amount"], reverse=True)
resultDict = {}
for value in sortedKeys:
  resultDict[value] = data[value]
print(resultDict)
```

##### Output

```
{'like': {'amount': 145, 'per': '0.5626%'}, 'so': {'amount': 83, 'per': '0.32203%'}, 'feel': {'amount': 54, 'per': '0.20952%'}}
```